Not able to add new entitys to a set when including only entity id in equals method
I wanted to ask about having the equals method on entities.
Im running a setup where Im only comparing entites based on Id and thought this is best way to do things. However I realized that when saving new UserRoles with cascaded persist then I run into problem where they are not unique initally since they dont have id yet. And so I cant add them to the set.
So my question is, is using only id field for equals a good approach? And is using cascades to persist related entitys a good approach? In my case it seems like I have to either add user and role fields to Equals (which I dont want to do beacause I dont want to have to load them eagerly all the time) or just persist the userRoles seperatly.
Context:
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = {"user", "role"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="kasutaja_roll")
public class UserRole extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "kasutaja_roll_id_seq", sequenceName = "kasutaja_roll_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "kasutaja_roll_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "kasutaja_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "roll_id")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "kehtiv_alates")
    private Instant validFrom;

    @Column(name = "kehtiv_kuni")
    private Instant validUntil;

    public UserRole(User user, Role role) {
        super();
        this.validFrom = Instant.now();
        this.user = user;
        this.role = role;
    }

}


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(exclude = {"roles"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true, callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "kasutaja")
public class User extends BaseEntity{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "kasutaja_id_seq", sequenceName = "kasutaja_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "kasutaja_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private Set<UserRole> roles;

...


and for example adding them like this:
for (Long roleId : requestDto.getRoles()) {
            UserRole existingUserRole = existingUserRolesByRoleId.get(roleId);

            if (existingUserRole == null) {
                // No existing userRoll - create new one
                Role role = roleRepository.findById(roleId)
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Role not found with id: " + roleId));
                UserRole newUserRole = new UserRole(user, role);
                user.getRoles().add(newUserRole); //!!!here adding multiple ones fails because they are equal, since id = null!!!
            } else if (existingUserRole.getValidUntil() != null) {
                // Existing userRole is inactive - reactivate it
                existingUserRole.setValidUntil(null);
                existingUserRole.setValidFrom(now);
            }
            //existing userRole is active, do nothing
        }



Rule of thumb, don't use Lombok, especially with JPA. You want to write the equals and hashCode yourself, there are several articles out there (like this one) on how to write a proper equals method. The article was written some time ago, so with new Java constructs this will be easier.

I'm of the opinion that if you don't have a reason to implement equals/hashcode - don't. Most code I have seen that rely on it use it for test purposes, as a short cut to compare two objects in unit tests. If you have a cache or look up mechanism, use a map with the entity's key as the lookup, not a set. You can then handle 'null' IDs appropriately (if needed). And Lists are better in entities (I still don't know why every Hibernate tutorial uses sets despite these issues with mutable fields).


So my question is, is using only id field for equals a good approach?

The short answer is no it isn't, the longer answer is it depends and you need to account for new instances.
There are many articles out there (like this one or more in-depth even this) that explain how to write a proper equals/hashCode method for JPA. There are some particularities you need to take into account.
Next to that JPA and Lombok are generally not friends is my experience (see this post of mine) and should be avoided. But that might be a personal vendetta.
All that being said you probably should write the equals/hashCode yourself. And a basic JPA implementation (with new Java constructs) could be something like this.
@Override
public boolean equals(Object that) {
  if (that instanceof UserRole ur) {
    return this.id != null && Objects.equals(this.id, that.id)
  }
  return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
  return getClass().hashCode();
}

Something like this should work. The instanceof check can be made smarter and you might even provide something like this in your BaseEntity.

Thanks for the anwser! Having looked more into implementing Equals and Hashcode on entitys it seems like not having one at all and defaulting to Objects equals method actually also works perfectly fine in most cases. What would be the upside of Overriding the Objects default Equals method in jpa entities or when would it be a good idea to do so?

Don't rely on the objects one. If you have 2 instances of the same entity they won't result in a proper equal for JPA. As they point to some memory location and not on the actual implementation.
